# Lifting a congruence $f(X) \equiv gh \ (\textrm{mod} \ q)$ to a higher power modulus

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have the polynomial ring $R = \mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^N - 1)$ with $N = 11$ and $h \in R$ with
\begin{equation*}
h = 7 -11X - 7X^2 -12X^3 + 8X^4 - 11X^5 + -8X^6 + 11X^7 - 4X^8 + 2X^9 + 3X^{10}
\end{equation*}
Now I want to find the polynomial $u$ such that
\begin{equation*}
u\cdot h + v\cdot (X^N - 1) \equiv X - 1 \ (\textrm{mod} \ 32)
\end{equation*}
where we assume $\gcd(h, X^N - 1) = X - 1$ reducing coefficients $\textrm{mod} \  32$. If we also let $*$ denote the multiplication in $R$, I can easily find $u$ such that $u*h \equiv X - 1 \ (\textrm{mod} \ 2)$ using the extended Euclidean algorithm, and it's $u = 1+X+X^{4}+X^{5}+X^{9}$, but I'm having issues using this to construct the solution such that $u' * h \equiv X - 1 \ (\textrm{mod} \ 32)$. Can someone outline an algorithm or link me some reading material on how to do this?

Comment: Lifting polynomial factorisations from $\mod p$ to $\mod p^k$ can be done using Hensel lifting; for example, see section 1.1.2 of http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/CAG/theses/garrett.pdf.

Comment: Using the notation of the provided text, the problem is $\gcd(u^{(1)}, h^{(1)}) = x \neq 1$ reduced $\mathrm{mod} \ 2$ and $\mathrm{mod} \ X^{11} - 1$, unless I'm mistaken. Can you clear up the confusion?